# Google classroom /education APIs Go from student to courses(And instructors) to assignments

Tags: c#, .net, google-workspace, google-classroom

I've been looking at the Google Classroom APIs, and it all seems to be organized top down, Teachers-> classes-> Assignments-> students.

We are making a student portal, and so I'd like to find a way to start with a student, find out their courses, and instructors, so I can list them, and show pending assignments.

Is there a way to do this, all I could see involved lots of data entry by instructors in our local DB, so w could have the Google class ids for each class tied to our local class structures.

Can we start with a student and dynamically use the api to figure the rest out?

I'm working in .Net and C#

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest) there are multiple endpoints where you can actually filter by the `studentId` or `userId`.

So imagine you have the `studentId` (the email works already as the id), you can get the courses of said student by using [`courses.list`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) informing the `studentId` in the [Query parameters](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list#query-parameters):

> Restricts returned courses to those having a student with the specified identifier. The identifier can be one of the following:

After that you can iterate every course for more information, but for example, if you want to get the submissions:

You would just list the submissions with [`courses.courseWork.list`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) and then you can filter the results of the submissions ([`courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list)) for each student informing the [Query parameter](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list#query-parameters) `userId`:

> Optional argument to restrict returned student work to those owned by the student with the specified identifier.

In the end there is no direct way to have an ID and return all, but there are several ways you can retrieve all the information of the student using the already intended parameters to filter the response to only one user relevant information.